# How to put a backup window for Networker job?

Tags: backup, emc, networker

I need to configure a Networker job than needs to start at a fixed time and to finish if it has not completed at a certain (later) time. That is, it has a fixed window.

But I do not manage to find any option in Networker to set an end time for a Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the hard runtime limit in the group's advanced configuration.

From the [Networker Administration Guide](http://oregonstate.edu/net/services/backups/clients/8_2/NetWorker-8.2-SP1-Administration-Guide.pdf):

**Hard runtime limit**

> This attribute indicates the time, in minutes, that any save
>   session still running is ended and the savegrp program stopped. The
>   default value is 0, which indicates that no Hard runtime limit is in
>   effect.